# performance issues with pandas apply

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe df

```
                                   time       u10  ...        av  kont
latitude  longitude                                ...                
51.799999 -3.2      2011-01-07 09:00:00 -2.217477  ...  0.008106  None
          -3.1      2011-01-07 09:00:00 -2.137205  ...  0.008202  None
51.900002 -3.1      2011-01-07 09:00:00 -2.276076  ...  0.008310  None
          -3.1      2011-01-07 10:00:00 -1.548405  ...  0.006344  None
          -3.0      2011-01-07 09:00:00 -2.200620  ...  0.008537  None
52.200001 -3.9      2011-01-05 23:00:00  1.393586  ...  0.005413  None
          -3.8      2011-01-05 21:00:00  1.972752  ...  0.007624  None
          -3.8      2011-01-05 22:00:00  1.732336  ...  0.006696  None
          -3.8      2011-01-05 23:00:00  1.551723  ...  0.005837  None
          -3.8      2011-01-06 00:00:00  1.377130  ...  0.004979  None
          -3.7      2011-01-05 21:00:00  2.124066  ...  0.008008  None
          -3.7      2011-01-05 22:00:00  1.892480  ...  0.007125  None
          -3.7      2011-01-05 23:00:00  1.710662  ...  0.006296  None
          -3.6      2011-01-05 21:00:00  2.259727  ...  0.008230  None
          -3.6      2011-01-05 22:00:00  2.044596  ...  0.007428  None
          -3.6      2011-01-05 23:00:00  1.865990  ...  0.006652  None
52.299999 -3.8      2011-01-05 23:00:00  1.652063  ...  0.006964  None
```

The entire dataframe can be downloaded from [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aj5DfuTWg1OMkNU2O4AMcaWwjdFF9g?e=Bi3jWm).

I need to sum groups within `latitude`, `longitude` and `kont`. I am doing this with following function though apply:

```
        def summarize(group):
            s = group['kont'].eq('from').cumsum()
            return group.groupby(s).agg(
                t2m=('t2m', 'mean'),
                av=('av', 'sum'),
                ah=('tp', 'sum'),
                d1=('time', 'min'),
                d2=('time', 'max')
            )
            
        df=df.groupby(['latitude', 'longitude']).apply(summarize).reset_index(level=-1, drop=True)
```

output is given [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aj5DfuTWg1OMkNU3EOtQI7hcl8uNrA?e=NIsHTd).
However, I need to run this on a large dataframe and it takes hours to finish these operations, probably because of the use apply.
Is there any pure pandas way of speeding this up? Is there any other way i.e. dask?

Comment: Tuned with 19.2 times faster with the provided sample data.  See if your large dataset can also have this big difference ?

Comment: Tried to %%timeit but, after more than hour, gave up and returned to proposed solution. Evenualy 2GB table finished in 10 min. Great job!

Comment: Great!  That's really substantial performance boost.  Pleased to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to change the codes as follows, without using `.apply()`:

```
s = df['kont'].eq('from').cumsum()
df = (df.groupby(['latitude', 'longitude', s])
        .agg(
             t2m=('t2m', 'mean'),
             av=('av', 'sum'),
             ah=('tp', 'sum'),
             d1=('time', 'min'),
             d2=('time', 'max')
         )
     ).reset_index(level=-1, drop=True)
```

**Result:**

Result is the same as running the original codes with `.apply()`:

```
print(df)

                          t2m        av        ah              d1              d2
latitude  longitude                                                              
51.799999 -3.2       0.099451  0.008106  0.010043   1/7/2011 9:00   1/7/2011 9:00
          -3.1       0.343713  0.008202  0.010375   1/7/2011 9:00   1/7/2011 9:00
51.900002 -3.1       0.097055  0.014654  0.020506  1/7/2011 10:00   1/7/2011 9:00
          -3.0       0.261560  0.008537  0.010545   1/7/2011 9:00   1/7/2011 9:00
52.200001 -3.9       0.292841  0.005413  0.010704  1/5/2011 23:00  1/5/2011 23:00
          -3.8       0.207666  0.025135  0.042585  1/5/2011 21:00   1/6/2011 0:00
          -3.7       0.354354  0.021428  0.031826  1/5/2011 21:00  1/5/2011 23:00
          -3.6       0.333602  0.022311  0.031084  1/5/2011 21:00  1/5/2011 23:00
52.299999 -3.8       0.012537  0.012992  0.024472  1/5/2011 23:00   1/6/2011 0:00
          -3.7      -0.146262  0.030848  0.047126  1/5/2011 21:00   1/6/2011 0:00
          -3.6       0.150072  0.031348  0.044772  1/5/2011 21:00   1/6/2011 0:00
52.400002 -3.8       0.240045  0.007225  0.013877   1/6/2011 0:00   1/6/2011 0:00
          -3.7       0.286981  0.015497  0.025990  1/5/2011 23:00   1/6/2011 0:00
          -3.6       0.167067  0.024722  0.036369  1/5/2011 22:00   1/6/2011 0:00
          -3.5       0.199080  0.024500  0.033631  1/5/2011 22:00   1/6/2011 0:00
          -3.4       0.258915  0.024050  0.030358  1/5/2011 22:00   1/6/2011 0:00
          -2.8       0.359186  0.009324  0.010351  1/7/2011 11:00  1/7/2011 11:00
          -2.7       0.241022  0.011714  0.010068  1/7/2011 10:00  1/7/2011 10:00
52.700001 -2.8       0.378778  0.009083  0.010874   1/6/2011 0:00   1/6/2011 0:00
          -2.7       0.314325  0.019510  0.022723  1/5/2011 23:00   1/6/2011 0:00
52.799999 -3.7       0.214777  0.007146  0.011296   1/6/2011 0:00   1/6/2011 0:00
          -3.6       0.294733  0.007325  0.010927   1/6/2011 0:00   1/6/2011 0:00
          -3.6       0.300104  0.005927  0.010070  1/7/2011 17:00  1/7/2011 17:00
          -3.5       0.314325  0.007460  0.010498   1/6/2011 0:00   1/6/2011 0:00
          -3.5       0.271021  0.005504  0.010115  1/7/2011 17:00  1/7/2011 17:00
52.900002 -3.9       0.204980  0.006496  0.011364   1/6/2011 0:00   1/6/2011 0:00
          -3.8       0.378778  0.006653  0.011136   1/6/2011 0:00   1/6/2011 0:00
          -3.6       0.370264  0.005485  0.010155  1/7/2011 18:00  1/7/2011 18:00
          -3.5       0.269434  0.007051  0.010269   1/6/2011 0:00   1/6/2011 0:00
          -3.5       0.372156  0.005216  0.010152  1/7/2011 18:00  1/7/2011 18:00
53.000000 -3.9       0.050775  0.006166  0.010510   1/6/2011 0:00   1/6/2011 0:00
53.200001 -1.9       0.396478  0.017476  0.012246  1/5/2011 23:00  1/5/2011 23:00
54.200001 -2.3       0.380670  0.014101  0.010786   1/6/2011 0:00   1/6/2011 0:00
54.299999 -2.4       0.183496  0.011351  0.010115   1/6/2011 0:00   1/6/2011 0:00
          -2.3       0.122034  0.025713  0.020119  1/5/2011 23:00   1/6/2011 0:00
```

#### Performance Comparison:

**Original codes using `.apply()`:**

```
%%timeit
def summarize(group):
            s = group['kont'].eq('from').cumsum()
            return group.groupby(s).agg(
                t2m=('t2m', 'mean'),
                av=('av', 'sum'),
                ah=('tp', 'sum'),
                d1=('time', 'min'),
                d2=('time', 'max')
            )
            
df.groupby(['latitude', 'longitude']).apply(summarize).reset_index(level=-1, drop=True)

303 ms ± 33.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Modified codes without using `.apply()`:**

```
%%timeit
s = df['kont'].eq('from').cumsum()
(df.groupby(['latitude', 'longitude', s])
        .agg(
             t2m=('t2m', 'mean'),
             av=('av', 'sum'),
             ah=('tp', 'sum'),
             d1=('time', 'min'),
             d2=('time', 'max')
         )
     ).reset_index(level=-1, drop=True)

15.8 ms ± 236 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

#### 303ms vs 15.8ms:  ~ 19.2 times faster